# How do I connect the phone cable in the breadboard

Tags: cables, breadboard, wireless-charging

I am making a wireless phone charger, and everything works, but I don’t know how to connect my cable to the receiver circuit. My cable has 4 terminals, and my receiver circuit is similar to this one.

[image]

Comment: Just strip and plug in the red and black wires. Ignore the other ones, those are for data transfer. Your phone won't fast-charge though unless they're hooked up to something.

Comment: Since current is low you can use a zener diode instead of a voltage regulator.

Comment: @MissMulan Is it better to use a zener diode? Others suggested to use a zener diode, but I don’t know why they prefer it than a voltage regulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You solder two solid copper wire 22AWG to the red and black wires such that you can insert those two copper wires into the breadboard. Shrink tubes on each wire is a good idea to prevent the wires from touching. The two other wires are not for power so you don't need to connect them.

Be careful not to ever short those two connections.  It could be catastrophic to the power source (computer or whatever.)

Answer (score 1):

There are USB to 0.1" pitch breakout boards, these will allow you to connect the USB cable to bread board.